# WKWebView decidePolicyFor after knowing mimeType drains memory

Tags: swift, swift5

I just saw that there is a new delegate for `WKWebView` for deciding to load a page after know its mimeType. This function blocks the UI and eventually kills the program. So I am wondering if I am doing something wrong if it’s just the way it is. Even dataTask isn’t memory consuming like this delegate.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

    if navigationResponse.response.mimeType?.containsDocs() == true {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        // some code here doing background processes.

        } else {      
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
}
```

I used to use dataTask to know the mimeType and it wasn’t draining the memory like that.